AUCTeX: Add "\Clause[optionlist]" to section commands, if package contract is loaded
There is a new LaTeX package: "contract". Inside a contract environment there are two new sectioning commands:
\Clause[optionlist]
\SubClause[optionlist]

The section command of Clause is on the level of a section, the SubSection is on the level of a subsection.
There are only optional arguments! So: \Clause{something}doesn't exist.
The most used command will be
\Clause[title=some clausetitle]

Q: Can you help me to make Emacs aware of this sectioning command in LaTeX/PS major mode (I guess this is done by AUCTeX)? If the contract package is loaded, I'd like to have a sectioning command \Clause[].
Please be aware, that there is a package scrjura which comes with a sectioning command \Clause{}. Unfortunately I have to use either scrjura or contract (never both in the same file, of course).
Almost ten years ago I've been asking a similar question. So I wrote a style file called "contract.el" and saved it besides the former "scrjura.el" in ~/.emacs.d/auctex/style.
Style files:
scrjura.el:
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "scrjura"
 (lambda ()
   (LaTeX-section-list-add-locally '(("Clause" 3)
            ("SubClause" 4)      
                     ("subsection" 4)
                     ("subsubsection" 5)
                     ("paragraph" 6)
                     ("subparagraph" 7)))
   (TeX-run-style-hooks
    "scrkbase"
    "tocbasic"))
 LaTeX-dialect)

contract.el:
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "contract"
 (lambda ()
   (LaTeX-section-list-add-locally '(("Clause" 3)
            ("SubClause" 4)      
                     ("subsection" 4)
                     ("subsubsection" 5)
                     ("paragraph" 6)
                     ("subparagraph" 7)))
   (TeX-run-style-hooks
    "scrkbase"
    "tocbasic"))
 LaTeX-dialect)

Having both style files doubles the output after C-=, I get the name of each clause twice. Q: If somebody could help me to get rid of double lines.
MWE:
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{contract}

\begin{document}
\begin{contract}
  \Clause[title=whatever first]

  Some text.

  Next paragraph.

  \Clause[title= Closing]

  Whatever more text. 
\end{contract}
\end{document}


One question per post, please.

I don't think it is possible to hook the macro \Clause which takes an optional key-val argument into the machinery how AUCTeX inserts sectioning commands without a bigger surgery.  Therefore I suggest you go the standard way by doing C-c C-m Clause RET where the corresponding AUCTeX style file can look like this (which is 0-tested):
;;; contract.el --- AUCTeX style for `contract.sty' (v0.91)  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defconst LaTeX-contract-clause-key-val
  '(("dummy")
    ("head")
    ("nohead")
    ("notocentry")
    ("number")
    ("preskip")
    ("postskip")
    ("title")
    ("tocentry"))
  "Key=val options for the \\Clause macro.")

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "contract"
 (lambda ()

   (LaTeX-add-environments
    '("contract"))

   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("Clause"
      [TeX-arg-key-val LaTeX-contract-clause-key-val])
    '("SubClause"
      [TeX-arg-key-val LaTeX-contract-clause-key-val])
    "Clauseformat"
    "thepar"
    "parformat"
    "parformatseparation"
    "withoutparnumber"
    '("ellipsispar" ["Number of paragraphs to omit"])
    "parellipsis")

   (let ((macs '("refL" "refS" "refN" "refClause" "refClauseN"
                 "refPar" "refParL" "refParS" "refParN"
                 "refSentence" "refSentenceL"" refSentenceS" "refSentenceN")))
     (dolist (mac macs)
       (TeX-add-symbols `(,mac TeX-arg-ref)))
     (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
                (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
       (font-latex-add-keywords
        (mapcar (lambda (x) (list x "{")) macs)
        'reference)))

   (LaTeX-paragraph-commands-add-locally '("Clause" "SubClause"))

   (LaTeX-add-counters "par" "sentence")

   ;; Fontification
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
              (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("contractSetup" "{")
                                ("ellipsispar"   "["))
                              'function)
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("Clause" "["))
                              'sectioning-2)
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("SubClause" "["))
                              'sectioning-3)))
 TeX-dialect)

(defconst LaTeX-contract-package-options-list
  (let ((len (mapcar (lambda (x) (concat TeX-esc (car x)))
                     (LaTeX-length-list))))
    `(("juratotoc" ("true" "false" "number"))
      ("juratocindent" ,len)
      ("juratocnumberwidth" ,len)
      ("contract")
      ("juratitlepagebreak" ("true" "false"))
      ("clausemark" ("both" "false" "forceboth" "forceright" "right"))
      ("parnumber" ("true" "false" "auto" "manual"))
      ("ref" ("long" "numeric"
              "clauseonly" "onlyclause" "ClauseOnly" "OnlyClause"
              "parlong" "longpar" "ParL"
              "parnumeric" "numericpar" "ParN"
              "paroff" "nopar"
              "parshort" "shortpar" "ParS" "sentencelong" "longsentence"
              "SentenceL"
              "sentencenumeric" "numericsentence" "SentenceN"
              "sentenceoff" "nosentence" "sentenceshort" "shortsentence"
              "SentenceS"
              "short"))))
  "Alist of package options for the contract package.")

(defun LaTeX-contract-package-option ()
  "Read the contract package options from the user."
  (TeX-read-key-val t LaTeX-contract-package-options-list))

;;; contract.el ends here


I suggest you take the above to auctex-devel mailing list and report back how it works.  Once the style is really operational, it can be added to AUCTeX distro.
